# Mysql query match against multiple possible characters

Tags: php, mysql, search, sql-like

I have the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `articles` 
WHERE (
        (
        UCASE(  `title` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% Fishoil %' ) 
        AND UCASE(  `title` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% for %' ) 
        AND UCASE(  `title` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% more %' ) 
        AND UCASE(  `title` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% musclemass %' )
        )
    OR (
        UCASE(  `text` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% Fishoil %' ) 
        AND UCASE(  `text` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% for %' ) 
        AND UCASE(  `text` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% more %' ) 
        AND UCASE(  `text` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% musclemass %' )
        )
    OR (
        UCASE(  `source` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% Fishoil %' ) 
        AND UCASE(  `source` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% for %' ) 
        AND UCASE(  `source` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% more %' ) 
        AND UCASE(  `source` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% musclemass %' )
        )
    OR (
        UCASE(  `unique` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% Fishoil %' ) 
        AND UCASE(  `unique` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% for %' ) 
        AND UCASE(  `unique` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% more %' ) 
        AND UCASE(  `unique` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% musclemass %' )
        )
    )
ORDER BY  `year` DESC
```

What I wish to do, is change

```
UCASE(  `tile` ) LIKE UCASE(  '% Fishoil %' )
```

into

```
 UCASE(  `title` ) LIKE UCASE(  '%Fishoil %' ) 
OR 
    UCASE(  `title` ) LIKE UCASE(  '%Fishoil,%' ) 
OR 
    UCASE(  `title` ) LIKE UCASE(  '%Fishoil.%' ) 
OR 
    UCASE(  `title` ) LIKE UCASE(  '%Fishoil:%' ) 
OR 
    UCASE(  `title` ) LIKE UCASE(  '%Fishoil;%' ) 
OR 
    UCASE(  `title` ) LIKE UCASE(  '%Fishoil\'%' ) 
OR 
    UCASE(  `title` ) LIKE UCASE(  '%Fishoil"%' ) 
OR 
    UCASE(  `title` ) LIKE UCASE(  '%Fishoil!%' ) 
OR 
    UCASE(  `title` ) LIKE UCASE(  '%Fishoil?%' )
```

But this seems to me to make the query unnessarily complex since it'll have to do the match several times. Is there a sort of regex match to match against the "searchterm + special character" in one go?

If so, what would be the best way to match against it?

This is the php code to generate the keyword search string

```
$specialchars = array(' ',',','.',':',';',mysql_real_escape_string("'"),'"','!','?');
foreach($seek as $searchword)
    {
    foreach($specialchars as $char)
        {
        $seeker[] = "LIKE UCASE(  '%$searchword".$char."%' )";
        }
    $temp = implode(" OR ",$seeker);
    echo $temp;
    }
```

Comment: Your query isn't that complex, just extremely _slooooooooow_: 3 things that are almost guaranteed to slow down a query: excess use of wildcards (`%`): check. Multiple `OR`'s in a WHERE clause: check. Bad indexing (probably check)

Comment: Yea well, it's a searchengine to search through 100 words texts in a digital library. Try searching without wildcards.
I could use suggestions to optimise this though.
Indexing is taken care of. I just need a better way to do the query, prefably regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), since they are much more powerful than the wildcard `LIKE` syntax. By using regex, you can fit the whole set of conditions into one `REGEXP` call (per column).

Comment: Okay, that is a suggestion I can do something with. I've been looking for this kind of thing but unable to find it. Bad googling I think.
I'll try to work on this. Thanks for the link!

Comment: If you're using UTF8 collation, which is probably the case, given the PHP tag, MySQL's REGEXP engine can produce unexpected results, though. Google for more info, but [here's a page on the mysql site that mentions this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,54660,54660)

Comment: There are other caveats as well, e.g. `LIKE` may use indexes in some cases, unlike regex. Not in your case, though.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding an or clause for each character, use an underscore (`_`). This acts like a wildcard, except for one thing: it's a place holder for a single char:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE 'visolie_';
```

Matches visolie!, visolie:, visolie?, and -because like is case *insensitive* ViSOliE!, too.

*Edit:*

To all intents and purposes: there are many good search engines that have been written by *Very* cleaver people, and are still being further developed by an army of competent programmers. Trying to create your own SE might be a good exercise, but when it really comes down to it, just use [CSE](http://www.google.com/cse/).
They've done the hard work for you, and being a developer means being lazy in a clever way. The whole point of open source software and, therefore, the web, is to avoid the necessity of constantly reinventing the wheel.

If you *absolutely* want to build your own SE, PHP&MySQL is proven technology, but perhaps not the best tool for the job. Try looking into faster DB (NoSQL?) alternatives (MongoDB springs to mind, as long as you're not constantly going to update your data, it's insanely fast. Again: choosing one means loosing the other, your data isn't as safely stored...). 
PHP is fairly fast, but takes up a lot of resources compared to, say, C++. I'm not sure if I got this right, but I'm prepared to bet quite a hefty sum of money saying that SE's like google, yahoo! and even crummy old Bing have quite a hefty C(++) codebase somewhere. No scripting language to date can outperform that, (and IMO never will there be a scripting language that can)

Comment: This may not work as expected, because "visolieW" will be matched as well. `_` stands for **any** character.

Comment: I don't want to match against everything. This would also match against visolien which I don't want. what @shedal said.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets: True, but this _will_ match `visoliecapsules`, which your current take won't. As you said, your taking a swing at building a search engine, which is all about choices, pro's and cons. The perfect engine doesn't exist, that's why google and co are under constant development. On google: they've invented the wheel for you, why not use their [custom search engine](http://www.google.com/cse/)? You'll never get something that good on your own! Remember: being a developer means being cleverly lazy

Comment: @MichaelDibbets: I've edited, or rather added, some more _"suggestions"_ to my answer. If you are building a SE, I'd say a query shouldn't make out for more than 15% of your SE's overall speed

Comment: Yes, i've read them. We specifically wish to exclude words where the search term is part of. Unless the person uses a wildcard(*) Plus the search we do is pretty specific with specific parts where google just can't search.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets: Ok, in that case a limited, self-made SE might make sense, but just a tip: consider creating a second table that logs the search terms and found results + the results that were clicked/used, to speed up the search as more ppl use it

Comment: That is on the todo list for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking at [**FULLTEXT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

You can do something like this;

```
SELECT *, MATCH(title,text,source,unique) AGAINST('fishoil for more musclemass') AS `score` FROM `articles` WHERE MATCH(title,text,source,unique) AGAINST('fishoil for more musclemass') ORDER BY `score` DESC, `year` DESC
```

whcih will return the results most relevant first.

You would have to alter your SQL table too;

```
ALTER TABLE articles ADD FULLTEXT(title,text,source,unique);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, but a search engine that does this kind of operations for _every_ search is pretty devastating for your server...